Methods of determining if an AI takeover on a planet has happened?
So, in my plot a Galactic Inspector incognito visits a planet (series of planets) with the mission to determine if an AI takeover has already happened there. If the planet is controlled by AI, the Galactic Fleet would have to destroy all activity on the planet.
How the inspector can determine the AI takover?

Providing your own answers and expecting more is specifically prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. To avoid question closure, you need to remove them. Note, also, that while not a direct duplicate of the following, the answers are relevant and should be reviewed to improve this question: (a) What are the conditions to confirm that we live in a simulation?, (b) How do we tell if we're living in a virtual reality world?, ... (*Continued*)

(c) Showing proof to humans they live in a simulated world, (d) Matrioshka Testing: A way to keep your AI honest (or at least guessing), (e) The Challenge of Controlling a Powerful AI, (f) How would a group of average people learn to behave in a simulation where a god-AI forces extreme plot devices on them for 10 years? and ... (*Continued*)

(g) Can you use an AI to shackle (control) an AI?. Finally, the reason we discourage brainstorming is because asking open-ended questions is prohibited by Stack Exchange in the [help/dont-ask] and asking about character actions or decisions is prohibited by us in the [help/on-topic].

@JBH I've deleted examples.

Thanks. Check out those other questions and find information that can help narrow yours. Along with that, give us an idea of what time we're dealing with (10 years from now? 100?) Please be as specific as you can be. Spend a paragraph identifying the political structure, any significant religious or educational structures, items that might reflect the tools the AI uses to enact its will. Finally, it would help to know the goals of the AI. since a "true" AI would be indistinguishable from a very smart human, we have only its nature and goals to work with and must know them to identify methods.

Hmmm... I think we have a problem. First, accept my congratulations! That's an excellent story idea that Isaac Asimov would approve of. Unfortunately, as it stands, you're not asking for help building your world, you're literally asking for help writing your story. The information you're asking for is the crux of the story, like the investigative techniques in Blade Runner. Indeed, how your investigator addresses the problem in each chapter is the very plot of your book, but as we state in the [help/on-topic], we don't help write stories.

On the other hand, an argument could be made that how the/each AI affects the world of each chapter might be a worldbuilding question (or, more specifically, a series of worldbuilding questions). How technology affects the underlying civilization or culture is permissible here, so long as the question is narrowly scoped and well defined. As it stands, I think this question is lost. If you disagree I'd recommend you delete it and ask it anew in our Sandbox.

@JBH no, his is not a question about AI. It is about how being a professional to detect AI takeover and differentiate it from just AI-saturated world.

I understand what you're saying, but in the end, you're asking us to explain how a character performs a duty. That's not worldbuilding unless you're asking us to help you develop a field of study. A field of study stands independent of a story - but I'm not sure how to ask this without you providing a reasonably detailed understanding of how AI works in your world. They are not universally defined and are often treated as godlike characters. You really need to look at those other questions and explain why they don't answer your question and I expect this Q to be closed for lack of details.

BTW, if you read the wikis or mouse roll-overs for the [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] tags you'll learn they're mutually exclusive. You need to choose one and delete the other.

Question: why specifically is AI bad in your setting? Because this I feel will be causal to what the Inspector looks for.

@TheDemonLord the Galactic Federation considers any civilization taken over by AI to be dangerous.

@Anixx - Why? merely saying it is Dangerous (especially given that the sanction is to destroy the planet) is not sufficient. This will help guide good answers to a good question.


Find if AI exists.
That's less obvious than it sounds. A world could put faith in non-intelligent computers for decisionmaking ("government based on operations research as an excuse to force a technocrat agenda on the people").
Find the potential AI and find out if it is willing to sit for a Turing Test. Or have the Galactics legislated themselves another standard?
Find if the AI has agenda-setting power.
There is a device in my home which decides to switch the heating on or off. Surely not an AI, it is based on a simple temperature sensor. Before I go out, I check the weather report to decide if I need a raincoat. By some definitions the models are based on AI, but humans are fully in control which questions get asked, the AI has no chance to insert an agenda ("link me up to those peripherals ASAP"). Same if a bank uses AI to decide if I should get a mortgage or if a social media company uses AI to rank my postings -- the AI is being asked narrow questions and giving narrow answers.
This means watching how the locals use AI. The problem is that it might miss a "hidden master" AI, say in the basement of a shadowy investment company or intelligence agency.
Judge if the locals have abandoned decisionmaking power.
Are they using AI as a tool to make better decisions, or are they letting themselves be used by AI? Say people are using AI to decide the optimal location of a new water treatment plant. Are they taking the answer with blind faith, or are they inserting human judgement? ("Putting the plant there may be perfect from an engineering viewpoint, but it spoils the scenic view. Give us another option.")


GPT-4 had recently passed the Turing test :P that idea is no longer valid. But determining the actual goal of a potential AI would be good, but if they can lie...
